# Publicar automaticamente no Facebook a partir do meu site

Tags: php, facebook

Como posso fazer uma publicação automática no face. Por exemplo tenho um blog que eu mesmo criei sem usar o Wordpress, criei em PHP com painel de controle e tal.

O que eu pensei em fazer é : Quando eu publicar um artigo no site, automaticamente o artigo ser publicado ou aparecer como uma postagem na minha linha do tempo no face. Como se eu tivesse feito uma postagem.

Comment: Já viu isto? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0

Comment: A resposta de bigown e um ponto perfeito para inciar. Um dethale: ele da o link para o SDK 4 o que é perfecto mas tem um monte de exemplos sobre isso, no Internet, usando SDK com versão menor que 4. Precisa bem verificar e usar somente SDK 4.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque pode ser resolvida com uma simples pesquisa na documentação oficial do facebook